# Angular 4 | Template bind through innerHTML, component variables are not accessible (damContentRoot is this case)

Tags: angular

We have to bind the template from API and then damContentRoot declared as the public variable in component. But it is not getting reflected.

```
   @Component({
    selector: 'app-plans',
    template: '<div *ngIf="pageTemplate" [innerHTML]="pageTemplate | safeHtml"></div>'
})
export class PlansComponent {
   public pageTemplate: string;
   public damContentRoot: string;
   public ngOnInit(): void {
   this.damContentRoot = "abcde";
   this.pageTemplate = `<div>Goog <span [innerHtml]="damContentRoot"></span>
                <span [innerHtml]="'<p>Yahoo</p>'"></span></div>`;

   }
}
```

damContentRoot do not get updated. Tried dynamic component but then damContentRoot become out of scope variable for that component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own directive that will do it:

**compile.directive.ts**

```
              @Directive({
                selector: '[compile]'
            })
                export class CompileDirective implements OnChanges {
            @Input() compile: string;
              @Input() compileContext: any;

                compRef: ComponentRef<any>;

                constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private compiler: Compiler) {}

                ngOnChanges() {
                    if(!this.compile) {
                        if(this.compRef) {
                            this.updateProperties();
                            return;
                        }
                        throw Error('You forgot to provide template');
                    }

                    this.vcRef.clear();
                    this.compRef = null;

                    const component = this.createDynamicComponent(this.compile);
                    const module = this.createDynamicModule(component);
                    this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module)
                        .then((moduleWithFactories: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) => {
                            let compFactory = moduleWithFactories.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === component);

                            this.compRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(compFactory);
                            this.updateProperties();
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                }

                updateProperties() {
                    for(var prop in this.compileContext) {
                        this.compRef.instance[prop] = this.compileContext[prop];
                    }
                }

                private createDynamicComponent (template:string) {
                @Component({
                        selector: 'custom-dynamic-component',
                        template: template,
                    })
                    class CustomDynamicComponent {}
                    return CustomDynamicComponent;
                }

                private createDynamicModule (component: Type<any>) {
                @NgModule({
                        // You might need other modules, providers, etc...
                        // Note that whatever components you want to be able
                        // to render dynamically must be known to this module
                        imports: [CommonModule],
                        declarations: [component]
                    })
                    class DynamicModule {}
                    return DynamicModule;
                }
            }
```

**Usage:-**

```
            import { Component, Input, NgModule } from '@angular/core'
            import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'

            import { CompileDirective } from './compile.directive';

            @Component({
                selector: 'my-app',
                template: `
            <div class="product"><ng-container *compile="template1; context: this"></ng-container></div>
            `,
            })
            export class App {
                damContentRoot = "abcde";
              @Input() template1: string = `<div>Goog <span [innerHtml]="damContentRoot"></span><span [innerHtml]="'<p>Yahoo</p>'"></span></div>`;
            }

            @NgModule({
                imports: [ BrowserModule ],
                declarations: [ App, CompileDirective ],
                bootstrap: [ App ]
            })
            export class AppModule {}
            }
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2Dbnbt8fBbXMJEd7c8jK?p=preview)

Comment: This works fine on local but fail with prod build. Says Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded

Comment: To use this in angular 6 you need to build without aot and build-optimizer: `ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false`

Comment: This makes the main.js file much bigger so it isn't a long term solution. In my case my main.js is 556k with a normal `--prod` build and 1.2MB with `--aot=false --build-optimizer=false`.

Answer (score 0):

**`pageTemplate`** is a string, but you are treating as a Boolean value in template , if you want to use it as above, you shoud convert it to a bollean value.

or check for the appropriate value in **`ngIf`**

```
template: '<div *ngIf="pageTemplate === 'yourStringvalue'" [innerHTML]="pageTemplate | safeHtml"></div>'
```

Comment: damContentRoot is not getting binded in innerHTML. Though it is the component public variable.